# How to specify the CSS files in cakephp?

Tags: validation, cakephp

I am getting the error "document type does not allow element "link" here" in W3 validations.I am specifying the CSS files in index.ctp file. The way i am specifying is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/homes.css" />
```

Comment: Sorry? The way you specifying is..?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/homes.css" />

Comment: Ah I didn't see it. It was not formatted properly. You need 4 spaces to start a code block.

Comment: what do you mean by 4 spaces?

Comment: Are you using this inside the HEAD tag?

Comment: @user2742023 This is not related to your question, but when you post a question you should prefix your codes using 4 spaces to form a code block. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I am using it in index.ctp file(in View).

Answer (score 1):

When W3C complains "Document type does not allow element "link" here", it implies that you are  probably not placing the `<link>` element inside a `<head>` tag properly.

In CakePHP, we uses [`HtmlHelper`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3acss) to emit these `link` tags properly by doing so:

1. Inline style:

   ```
   //this will echo out the link tag at this exact point
   echo $this->Html->css('your-css-script.css');
   ```
2. Css in the header. Assume you have `echo $this->Html->fetch('css')` in your main `layout.ctp`, that's where all the non-inline css link will be emitted.

   ```
   //this will be placed on top of your layout
   $this->Html->css('your-css-script.css', null, array('inline' => false));
   ```
3. Multiple CSS scripts:

   ```
   $this->Html->css(array('css1.css', 'css2.css',..));
   ```

Also note that the extension `.css` is not required, though it looks nicer to have it there. Try a few of the combinations above and ensure your `<link>` tag is in your `<head>`.

**Edit**

To further clear the doubt about non-inline css, when you have such set up:

`/View/Layouts/default.ctp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout ?></title>
    <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');
    ?>
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

And your view:
`/Layouts/View/Users/index.ctp`:

```
<?php $this->Html->css('homes', null, array('inline' => false)); ?>
Hello world!
```

The `homes.css` should goes, automatically, into the `$this->fetch('css');` code block in your layout. This is especially good when you want your layout lean, and include css in the head instead of scattering it around in your rendered html.

Comment: Better than my answer because it mentions placing css in the head.

Comment: Thanks. I thought he's emitting the css tag from other places so I think it would be nice to let him know the idea of having non-inline css calls. It makes your main layout lean and less clutter if some css rules is required by certain views only.

Comment: I am specifying it in    <?php  echo $this->Html->css('homes'); ?> in index.ctp file but still it is showing me an error in W3 Validations. If i specify that in default layout in <head> tag, my whole layout changes.

Comment: The one you are trying is echoing it out inline, meaning you are echoing out mid of `<body>` tag. Try do this: `<?php $this->Html->css('homes', null, array('inline' => false)); ?>` instead. I take into assumptions that you have `<?php echo $this->Html->fetch('css'); ?>` in your rendering layout, or `/View/layouts/default.ctp`.

Comment: Sorry typo. Instead of `$this->Html->fetch('css')`, should be `$this->fetch('css')`. See my edited post for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your layout files `View/Layouts/default.ctp`

For one (css/screen.css)

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('screen');?>
```

For more than one

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css(array('bootstrap','screen'));?>
```